# Unable to update data in pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, crud, pymongo-3.x

I have a JSON `POST` data that a user is going to send me every time to fetch some data from a third party service.I plan to cache the data based on a scope id so that I don't keep inserting the data each time the user requests for something.Futhermore I am keeping a time stamp for each user request.Below is the `POST` data that user is going to send me everytime.

```
{
        "scope_id": "user1",
        "tool_id": "appdynamics",
        "api_id": "get metrics",
        "input_params": {"user": "myuser", "pwd": "mypwd", "acc_id": "myaccount", "app_id": "TestApp", "metric-path": "ars", 
        "time-range-type": "BEFORE_NOW", "duration-in-mins": 10},
        "output_filters": {}
}
```

Below is the code snippet to handle the insertion of data

```
def post(self):
    data = ServiceAPI.parser.parse_args()
    print("First data", data)
    scope_id = data["scope_id"]
    tool_id = data["tool_id"]
    api_id = data["api_id"]
    input_params = data["input_params"]
    output_filter = data["output_filter"]

    if all([scope_id, tool_id, api_id]) and all(input_params.values()): 
        check_id = [j for i in users.find({}) for j in i if j == scope_id]
        if check_id and check_id[0] == scope_id:
            users.update({scope_id: [tool_id, api_id, input_params]},
                         {scope_id: [tool_id, api_id, input_params], 
                              "timestamp": datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, upsert=True)
        else:
            users.insert_one(
                {scope_id: [tool_id, api_id, input_params],
                "timestamp": datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')})
```

Here the update statement works great if the user request is exactly the same as last time but makes a new entry if the user demands a new information for example in the `POST` request `api_id = "get logs"` when ideally it should have updated the user's data with the latest one.

For the first time when the user makes a `POST` request, below is the data that gets stored in my database

```
[{'user1': ['appdynamics', 'get metrics', {'pwd': 'mypwd', 'metric-path': 'ars', 'user': 'myuser', 'time-range-type': 'BEFORE_NOW', 'acc_id': 'myaccount', 'app_id': 'TestApp', 'duration-in-mins': 10}], 'timestamp': '2018-03-24 21:49:28', '_id': ObjectId('5ab67a901899db6d8a266558')}]
```

Now I make the same request again, it ensures no new entry is made since its made by the same **scope id**

However now if the user requests some new information for example

```
{
        "scope_id": "user1",
        "tool_id": "appdynamics",
        "api_id": "get logs",
        "input_params": {"user": "myuser", "pwd": "mypwd", "acc_id": "myaccount", "app_id": "TestApp", "metric-path": "ars", 
        "time-range-type": "BEFORE_NOW", "duration-in-mins": 10},
        "output_filters": {}
}
```

Notice I have changed `"api_id": "get logs"`, it makes a new entry instead of just modifying the existing data in my database.Here is the data now

```
[{'user1': ['appdynamics', 'get metrics', {'pwd': 'mypwd', 'metric-path': 'ars', 'user': 'myuser', 'time-range-type': 'BEFORE_NOW', 'acc_id': 'myaccount', 'app_id': 'TestApp', 'duration-in-mins': 10}], 'timestamp': '2018-03-24 21:49:28', '_id': ObjectId('5ab67a901899db6d8a266558')}, {'user1': ['appdynamics', 'get logs', {'pwd': 'mypwd', 'metric-path': 'ars', 'user': 'myuser', 'time-range-type': 'BEFORE_NOW', 'acc_id': 'myaccount', 'app_id': 'TestApp', 'duration-in-mins': 10}], 'timestamp': '2018-03-24 21:55:29', '_id': ObjectId('5ab67bf9089b16e9e77037f4')}]
```

So here the update seems to fail.What could be going wrong?

**Note**: This is a flask app and I suggest not to get into the details of the implementation.I just need to update the given data based on the **scope id** each time a user makes a request irrespective of whether it is the same request or a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing upsert=True to update(). Upsert tells MongoDB to update an existing document if one matching the query is found, insert a new document otherwise. The first parameter to update() is a query filter to find documents to apply the update to. The update query filter where api_id == "get logs" isn't matching any existing document, so a new document is being created.